# Getting The SSL connection could not be established error while installing Build Agent on Azure Server

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ssl-certificate, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I am trying to install a self-hosted build agent on my azure server and I am unable to install it due to below error,

[image]

However, I am able to install it on my other server without any error. I am not sure what am I missing on the server where I am getting the above error.

I had tried using the --sslskipcertvalidation as well but no success. I also created a self signed SSL cert as well by referring the below URL but still the issue exist.

https://thycotic.force.com/support/s/article/Installing-a-Self-Signed-SSL-HTTPS-Certificate

Comment: Check the domain personal token your entering, validate that with jwt.io to make sure it has valid audience